# A word for drain plugs in boats

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, old-english, pirate-english, nautical-terms

In row boats, and similar boats, there is a *drain plug*, which is taken out when it is ashore, to empty for water. In Norwegian the term used is 'nygle', and in Icelandic 'negla'. In contemporary English it seems that the term in use is 'drain plug'.

Did English have one word, as e.g. 'spigot', for drain plugs? If so, what was it?

Comment: Aren't they _bungs_?

Comment: Recreational boats: drain plugs is generic. spigot requires being turned on.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey My understanding is that they are for casks, and the etymology 
suggests that 'bung' is not old enough as drain plugs were common long before the fifteenth century.

Comment: https://www.chmarine.com/boat-plugs-drain-bungs/

Comment: Bung  Fishing; colloquial name for live baits like yellowtail Boating; the rubber plug/s under the transom removed to drain the boat or hull of trailerable boats after returning to shore and retrieving the vessel [What is a Bung?](https://chsmith.com.au/Wiki/Bung.html)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sure. As indicated, I am interested in words with a longer historical provenance. One should expect there to have been drain plugs in Great Britain in the fourteenth century, and before William the Conqueror as well.

Comment: I doubt very much that anyone called these things 'drain plugs' in the 14th century.

Comment: Indeed! Nor did they call them 'bungs'.

Comment: I've been able to date *boat's plug* only to 1832 and *boat-plug* to 1853.

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether the Norwegians and Icelanders use "nylge" and "nöldur" for the plugs found in sinks and baths. It would also be interesting to know whether there is a verb in either language which means to

Comment: @BoldBen 'nygle' is not used for plugs in sinks or baths in Norwegian, nor is it used for any other plugs. 'nygle' is as well a verb, for the act of plugging the 'nygle' into the boat's 'nyglehol'.

'nöldur' was an unfortunate misinformation, from a Norwegian site. From Ivar Aasens authoritative Norsk Ordbog, 1873, we get the information that Icelandic has 'kegla', which I am quite certain is also a verb.

Comment: The fact that Icelandic has the word "negle", with the same meaning as "nygle" in Norwegian, suggests that drain plugs existed already during the time of the vikings. So one should expect there to have been a word for drain plugs in Old English.

Comment: *nagle*, *negla*, etc, are cognates of *nail* (either for fastening or fingernail), related to Latin *unguis* (fingernail). The OED lists *naegl* as Old English for a small metal spike, but gives an example from 1440 where it is used for a similar wooden spike. There don't seem to be surviving texts, but I'd bet that a variant of *nail* would be the most likely.

Comment: It's not clear from ***Did** English have one [sic] word ...?*  whether you want an old word that's still in use or are willing to have an old word that is no longer used.

Comment: @TimR Both interpretations are reasonable, and both words which circulate, and those that do not circulate any more, are of interest to me.

Comment: @StuartF Your observation is very interesting. I would like it if you developed it into an answer.

Comment: Old Icelandic **negla**, u, f. the bung to close a hole in the bottom of a boat which lets out the bilge-water. *Icelandic-English Dictionary*,  initiated by Richard Cleasby, revised by Gudbrand Vigfusson, 2nd edition  with supplement by Sir William Craigie, (Oxford, 1957).

Comment: The only nautical contexts I can find for **nægel** in Old English refer to the handle of a helm and to the fastening with nails the overlapping planks of ships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found evidence that the word *scyttel* was used in Old English for a boat plug. It is mentioned in the book "[Etymological and Pronouncing Dictionary of Difficult Words](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Etymological_and_Pronouncing_Dictionary/0HYCAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=old%20english%20%22scyttel%22%20plug&pg=PA1072&printsec=frontcover)" by Ebenezer Cobham Brewer, published in 1882:

> [image]
>
> Old English *scyttel*, a bolt or bar. A plug in the bottom of a ship.

In the excerpt above, *scyttel* is given as the Old English form of *scuttle* which is a current nautical term. *OED* gives the oldest form of *scuttle* as *skottelle* from Middle English and doesn't mention Old English *scyttle* in the etymology of *scuttle*; and gives the year 1497 for the first attestation of the original and current nautical sense.

> *Nautical*. A square or rectangular hole or opening in a ship's deck smaller than a hatchway, furnished with a movable cover or lid, used as a means of communication between deck and deck; also a similar hole in the deck or side of a ship for purposes of lighting, ventilation, etc.
>
> **1497**
> A chayne of yron for the skottelles of the haches.
> <sub>in M. Oppenheim, *Naval Accounts & Inventories Henry VII* (1896) 323</sub>
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “scuttle, n.², sense 1.a”, July 2023. 
> https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/6910297135</sub>

*OED* says of unknown origin for *scuttle* but mentions the possible French origin:

> The English word is commonly believed to be adopted from the French, and this from the Spanish; but the relation between the three, and the ultimate etymology, remain uncertain. According to a quotation given by Jal, the French word formerly meant the hatch or trapdoor covering the hatchway; if this was the original sense, the word might be a derivative of Dutch or Low German *schutten* to shut; compare English *shuttle* (of a dam).
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “scuttle, n.², Etymology”, July 2023.
>  https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/7095634123</sub>

The obsolete word *shuttle* with the sense "A bolt or bar, as of a door" is from Old English *scyttel* also; and *OED* mentions in the etymology that it is ultimately from a prehistoric word with the primitive sense 'to shut'.

> **Old English** *scyt(t)el, scyt(t)els* < prehistoric **skutil, -isli*, < *skut- in *scyttan* to shut; the two Old English words have different suffixes, but their forms coalesced in Middle English: see -el *suffix*<sup>1</sup>, -els *suffix*. Compare West Frisian *skoattel*, East Frisian *schötel*, North Frisian *sködel*.
>
> **Notes** 
> The modern dialect shuttle (*shittle, shettle, shottle*) horizontal bar of a gate (see *Eng. Dial. Dict.*), is perhaps the same word.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “shuttle, n.², Etymology”, July 2023. 
>  https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/1195563136</sub>

Comment: The Early Modern English nautical meanings of "rectangular openings" and "hatches" are clearly an extension of the Middle English **shittel** "slot in a door" which is an extension of the Old English **scyttel**  meaning "sluice, sluice-gate". But what is Ebenezer Cobham's attestation from the Old English period for **scyttel** where it means "a plug in the bottom of a ship"? Without attestation there's no evidence.

Comment: Well, my evidence is the book I've quoted from, and also the etymological explanation and current usages of the modern forms support the evidence. But of course, it doesn't seal the deal without an example usage in Old English.

Comment: The connection is not implausible, but if the book you're quoting from doesn't present any evidence, it's not evidence. The Middle English Dictionary is a huge scholarly undertaking  many years in the making, and it is available on the web. The Dictionary of Old English project at University of Toronto is likewise such an undertaking; the DOE provides the corpus of Old English for a pretty penny (over $200). I don't find any nautical uses of **scyttel** in the OE corpus. There is the shuttle of a loom, which in Latin is *nauicula*, as it is shaped like a little boat.

Comment: Ebenezer Cobham  was an interesting man, who worked a lot. So I take him seriously, and consider the answer above evidenced. :) Note however, that the statement is that scuttle applies to ships, and it is not clear that it applies to boats. Perhaps someone can do better, for 1497 is not so long ago as the Vikings raid upon Paris.

Answer (score 2):

The word **bung** works. [Wiktionary defines it as:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bung)

> A stopper, alternative to a cork, often made of rubber, used to prevent fluid passing through the neck of a bottle, vat, a hole in a vessel etc.

Wiktionary gives this example sentence, which shows how this word is used regarding boats:

> With the heavy seas trying to broach the boat they baled — and eventually found someone had forgotten to put the bung in.

(To see it, you have to click the "quotations" link next to the relevant sense of the word. Wiktionary attributes the quote to "1996, Dudley Pope, *Life in Nelson's Navy*.")

[Cambridge also gives this attested example:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/example/english/bung)

> The fine boats he defined as fuel tax, income tax, and all the others, and from every one of these he himself pulled the bung so that they sank.

Comment: "boat" and "baled" are not on the Wiktionary page linked to.

etymonline.com does not list a maritime origin.

Comment: @Sapiens I've updated to make it clear that you need to click the "quotations" link on Wiktionary to see it.

Answer (score 1):

*Bilge plug* is a term used. *Bilge* is a nautical term meaning the lowest inner part of a ship's hull, where water collects. The water accumulated can also be called *bilge*. Another relevant term is a *scupper* which means the drain hole in a ship's side to allow water to run off the deck.

[*Merriam Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bilge%20plug) lists the term *bilge plug* and gives the year 1883 for the first known use:

> : BOAT PLUG 
> If your boat has a *bilge plug*, remove the plug when the boat is out of the water so that any water that has accumulated in the bilge can drain free. 
> —Twain Braden, *The Handbook of Sailing Techniques*, 2003

Comment: The Norwegian "nygle" certainly has a  m u c h  older provenance than back to 1883, and the British sailed already in the middle ages. So there must be a much older English word, which would be more interesting, to the same degree.

Comment: _Stopper_ is an earlier word for this usage from 1667 per _OED_, and _stoppel_ is an earlier version of _stopper_ from a1400 per _OED_. So we can go back to Middle English at least. In Old English, perhaps a generic word was used, like a _top_ which goes back to OE. Or perhaps, there was a word adopted from Old Norse but I couldn't find evidence. There are some books about Old English sea terms but I couldn't access.

Comment: The stopper is somewhat early, but not quite. :) The Scandinavian vikings sailed the Seine, and occupied Paris, before 900; hence Normandie, and William the Conqueror. They certainly had "nygler", as the boats were sometimes carried ashore; they as well had the word for it, as a derivation is found in Icelandic.

Comment: 1450. **thurrok**  "There ys a place in the bottome of a shyppe wherein ys gatheryd all the fylthe that cometh in to the shyppe..And that place stynketh ryghte fowle, and yt ys called in some contre of thys londe a thorrocke."  From OE **þurruc**

Comment: You could probably use **peg** : ***thurrok-pegge**  but **peg** comes into English from Middle Dutch.  Or **pin** which is from OE **pin**.

Comment: @TimR _OED_ gives the sense "the bilge of a ship" for the obsolete _thurrok_ (from OE _þurruc_). It doesn't mention drain/boat/bilge plug. Is it clear in your ME example that _thorrocke_ means a boat plug?

Comment: @ermanen OE  **þurruc**  means "keel, skiff" glossing Latin *cumba*.  Middle English **thurrok** means "the bilge of a ship". That's why I said you could use (unattested) ***thurrok-peg** or ***thurrok-pin**.  **peg** and **pin** are both attested, but not in connection with **thurrok**.

Comment: @TimR Thanks got it. I've also found evidence that OE _scyttel_ was used for a boat plug which evolved into _shuttle_ and/or _scuttle_. _Scuttle_ is a nautical term also for a small hatch or an opening in a boat. I couldn't find an OE example sentence with _scyttel_ meaning a boat plug though. I might try to post an answer later.

Comment: @ermanen: A **scyttel** in OE is a bar  or a bolt, as for a door or a gate. I don't find any OE nautical contexts. What is your attestation?

Comment: @ermanen a **shittel** in Middle English is a bar or a bolt (door/gate) or a slot in a door,  a sluice-gate; or a weapon  bolt (e.g. cross-bow arrow) and it can also refer to the shuttle of a loom. But I don't find any clearly nautical uses.